# How to do polynomial composition/substitution? (Vincent-Alesina-Galuzzi)

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, roots

For the polynomial 
$$ 
 p(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n c_i x^i, 
$$
of real coefficients and real variable, obtain the coefficient of
$$
q(x) = \left(1 + x\right)^n p\left( \frac{a + b x}{1 + x} \right),
$$
as efficiently as possible.

This problem arises when one try to implement the [Vincent-Alesina-Galuzzi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincent%27s_theorem)
root-brackting algorithm.
Ultimatly, the goal is to count the number of sign change in the coefficient of $q(x)$.

I found a few expressions for $q(x)$
\begin{align}
q(x) &= \left(1+x\right)^n \sum_{i=0}^n c_i\left(\frac{a+b x}{1+x}\right)^i, \tag{1} \\ 
&= \sum_{i=0}^n c_i \left(a +b x\right)^i \left(1+x\right)^{n-i}, \tag{2} \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^i \sum_{k=0}^{n-i} c_i \binom{i}{j} a^{i-j} \left(b x \right)^{j} \binom{n-i}{k} x^{k} \tag{3} 
\end{align}
but I don't see an efficient implementation for either (1), (2) or (3).

mathreadler mentionned convolution. I think this point to the Fourier transform that may simplify the inner sums in (3). But, I'm not sure if this is efficient.

Comment: Post in math stack

Comment: This question should be asked in Mathematics.SE

Comment: Is `p(x)` guaranteed to be divisble by `1 + x`?

Comment: @KerrekSB, No, the coefficients of `p(x)` are randomly generated.

Comment: Then run the division algorithm...

Comment: @KerrekSB Thanks Kerrek, your comment made me realized. The theorem says to perform the substitution `(1 + x)^n p( (a + b x) / (1 + x) )`. This implies that there is no division, and I can adapt Horner.

Comment: You can do it by convolution followed by deconvolution. This is because multiplication of polynomials becomes convolution of it's coefficients. If I was better at Fortran I could show you, but I am only good enough in Matlab/Octave to express it in a nice way.

Comment: Strictly speaking, if $a\neq b$ then $q(x)$ is not a polynomial, so what does it mean to compute its coefficient? The coefficients of the principal part of the Laurent series in zero? The whole Laurent series?

Comment: You can solve the denominator = 0 followed by partial fractions if you want. Or maybe estimate a Laurent series as Jack mentions. For some applications maybe it would be OK with doing an ordinary polynomial division and even disregard the remainder. It all depends on what you want to do with the result.